# How do I find the ID of an element that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Say I have an many html elements, a row in a table composed of table data (`<td>`) tags.

```
<td id="data1">foo</td>
<td id="data2">bar</td>
<td id="data3">baz</td>
```

How would I return the `id` of the `td` that was clicked. I know that I should make them links so that I can click on them properly, but just for this case I don't want to put links.

```
$("td").click(function () {
  id = //The ID finder goes here
  clickFunction(id)
 }
```

I was thinking this is how it would be formatted. JQuery would attach an onclick event listener to any table data tags and when it fired, a function would run with the id of the table data element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, `this.id`:

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  console.log(this.id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="data1">foo</td>
    <td id="data2">bar</td>
    <td id="data3">baz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did the **Run code snippet** thing and it just printed out the ID's of all of the `<td>` elements. Is there a reason this is happening? Will it work normally, just not on this code run program?

Comment: @Spaceface16518 What browser are you using? This should log the ID of only the element you clicked, tested in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE 11

Comment: Thanks @j08681, it works with Chrome. On Safari, it just logged all of the ID's of the `td` elements.

Comment: @Spaceface16518 Sounds like Safari's problem (one of the many)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code: `$(this).attr('id')`.

Comment: or `this.id` (too much jQuery!)